# Neural net fitting in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-figure

I am trying to find the optimum number of neurons to use to run the Neural Net Fitting tool in Neural Networks Matlab app.

I am currently using 62000 samples of 64 elements as input and 62000 samples of 1 element as target. I tried to obtain similar results as in data obtained through other means, but the results are not even similar when trying to run the tool with 1-12 neurons. I tried running it with 64 neurons and the results were closer to what it was expected.

Is there any kind of way to know how many neurons to use based on the number of elements/samples?

Any suggestions on how to select the number of neurons when running the tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for simple datasets like MNIST I will at minimum use 128 neurons. Possible values to check are 128, 256, 512, and maybe 1024. These numbers are just easy to remember and are not magical nor the consequence of a known formula. Alternatively, choose a few random samples from [100, 500] and see which number of neurons worked best. Harder tasks tend to require more neurons, and when you have many neurons you need to consider regularizing your network with L_2 regularization or dropout.